# How to show that $(\operatorname{Im}{A})^⊥ = \ker(A^⊤)$, $\operatorname{Im}{(A^⊤)}= (\ker A)^⊥$?

Tags: vector-spaces

Let now $A ∈ L(V)$, where $V$ be an Euclidean vector space.

I need to show that:

$$(\operatorname{Im}{A})^⊥ = \ker(A^⊤)$$
$$\operatorname{Im}{(A^⊤)}= (\ker A)^⊥$$

Comment: this is not always true in infinite dimension I think btw

Comment: in infinite dimension, one only has $closure(Im A^T) \subset {ker A}^\perp$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should do it

$$ \forall y \in V.\forall x \in V. \langle Ax, y \rangle = \langle x, A^Ty \rangle$$

Comment: How to show that  $(A^⊤)^⊤ \subseteq A$?

Comment: @qexi, I think you meant $\;\left(A^t\right)^t=A\;$ ? It can't be a contention relation here as $\;A\;$ is not a set but a matrix.

Comment: No, I mean that $A$ is  a set. Let's use $U$ for example. I don't know how to show that $(U^⊥)^⊥ = U$ & $(U^⊤)^⊤⊆U$.

Comment: @qexi this is another question. and one for which you might be surprised by the answer :)

Comment: @qexi, but **you** defined $\;A\;$ as a matrix!

Comment: @Timbuc he refers to another question I think